# React-Native (FlatList): How to know when the rendering of visible items has finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

When using a FlatList Component in react native I need to know when all the visible items have been rendered.

I am providing `data` and the `renderItem` when I get the `componentDidMount` I can see the FlatList there but because FlatList Component asynchronously renders each item they only show up after on `componentDidUpdate`. Also, this could (and probably will) include off-view items.

I would like to know if there is someone out there that has found a possible way to have a controlled process (not with `setTimeout`) of knowing when the visible items are fully rendered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the `componentDidMount` of the `renderItem` component as an indicator that element is rendered.

In the below example `ActivityIndicator` will be shown until the first 10 items are rendered (the number I set in the `initialNumToRender`).

This approach is not ideal. You may need to tweak it for your case but the general idea is shown below.

Here is the list item:

```
class ListItem extends React.Component<{ onRendered: () => void }> {

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.onRendered();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Item</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the screen with `FlatList` that uses above ListItem:

```
export class FlatListTestScreen extends React.Component<any, { creating: boolean }> {
  constructor(props: any, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      creating: true,
    };
  }

  onRenderedItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      creating: false,
    });
  };

  renderItem = (item: any) => {
    return <ListItem onRendered={this.onRenderedItem} />;
  };

  dataArray = Array(20)
    .fill('')
    .map((_, i) => ({ key: `${i}`, text: `item #${i}` }));

  render() {
    const loader = this.state.creating ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <></>;
    return (
      <View>
        {loader}
        <FlatList
          initialNumToRender={10}
          data={ this.dataArray }
          renderItem={ this.renderItem }
          keyExtractor={ item => item.key }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to use a map to collect the number of rendered items but on practice it seems that they all fire `componentDidMount` at the same time so simpler approach may be better.